# Setting 2 dives with padding of 10 px

Tags: html, css

I have simple html page which works with 2 bootstrap and some handwrting css.
Here is the `html` page:

```css
    .header {
      width: 1024px;
      height: 60px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
    }
    .gotoAndBot {
      width: 109px;
      height: 20px;
      font-family: Roboto;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-style: normal;
      font-stretch: normal;
      letter-spacing: 0.2px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #62e2c0;
    }
    #gal-bot-marvin-jpg {
      width: 40.7px;
      height: 41.7px;
    }
    .Oval-3 {
      width: 42.9px;
      height: 44px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border: solid 4px #62e2c0;
    }
```

```html
     <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
              <div class="row" style="padding-left:10 px;">
                  <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <!--img id="Oval-3" src="../assets/robot.png"-->
                      <div class="Oval-3">
                        Robot
                      </div> 
                  </div>        
                  <div>
                      <div class="col-sm-1 gotoAndBot " style="padding-left:10 px;">
                              gotoAndBot      
                      </div>
                  </div> 
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

I need to put the `Oval-3` class with a 15 px `margin` from the inner side div tag (`header`).
Also, there should be 10 px margin between 2 divs in the row (`Oval-3` and the `gotoAndBot` )
But it is not like it?

Comment: there should be no space in `padding-left:10 px;` so it should be `padding-left:10px;`

Comment: Yes, you right. but still the space between two elements are too big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to remove a space in `style="padding-left:10px;"` in block with classes `gotoAndBot` and `row`
2. If you want to have some space within `div.header`, you can add `padding: 15px;` to this block. But keep in mind that you will also need to remove fixed height, otherwise, it won't work the way you want. For example, instead of using fixed height, you can use `min-height: 60px;`
3. To have a space of 10px between 2 divs in the row (`Oval-3` and the `gotoAndBot` ), you will need to rewrite some bootstrap classes. Because bootstrap classes like `col-sm-1` etc have `padding-right`, `padding-left` and `width` set by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think your HTML is confusing bootstrap, which has it's own padding rules. You can override these rules to be sure, but it might be easier not to use bootstrap for this bit of your layout.

You're attempting to override bootstrap's "row" padding with inline CSS and .col-sm-1.gotoAndbot is also wrapped in a DIV, but I don't think it need be.

```
                <style>
                .header {
                  width: 1024px;
                  height: 60px;
                  background-color: #ffffff;
                  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
                }
                .gotoAndBot {
                  width: 109px;
                  height: 20px;
                  font-family: Roboto;
                  font-size: 15px;
                  font-weight: 500;
                  font-style: normal;
                  font-stretch: normal;
                  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
                  text-align: center;
                  color: #62e2c0;
                    float: left;
                    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
                }
                #gal-bot-marvin-jpg {
                  width: 40.7px;
                  height: 41.7px;
                }
                .Oval-3 {
                  width: 42.9px;
                  height: 44px;
                  background-color: #ffffff;
                  border: solid 4px #62e2c0;
                    margin: 0 0 0 15px;
                    float: left;
                }
                </style>
                <div class="container">
                   <div class="header">
                                 <div class="Oval-3">
                                   Robot
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="gotoAndBot">
                                         gotoAndBot
                                 </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
```